# C# Winforms: Mapping local Documents and retrieve them via Datagridview hyperlink's cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, hyperlink, mapping

I'm using winform 4.7. on visual studio 2019.
First, I carry some documents like the electricity, gaz and leisure bills of person id 3, person id 4 and so on in 3 different languages.
I have a datagridview that gets its data from a sql table with columln 1 = id (that corresponds to the person id of my documents on my local computer). What i'm trying to do is: when I click on any datagridview's cell of the first column(the id's column), it opens a new form, ask me a choice between the language EN/FR/IT (I guess a listbox within the form), asks me the type of document, "electricity bill" / "gaz bill" / "leisure bill" and then build my output string with the answers I gave or clicked on. Let's say for example, I double cliked on the ID 3 within the datagridview, and selected "English" and "electricity bill" from the form that poped up. Then, it build a string which will ultimately be a hyperlink like this: C://folder/personId3_electricityBill_EN thats will give me the electricity bill of person 3 in english stored in my pc at this adress.

I worked on a prior project like this where I "mapped" each document in each language for each person in a spreadsheet and loop through it. But it was on excel...

Now I use a datagridview to display my data, and there isn't any other tab where I can map the things (for the better I guess).
Before I go anywhere, for what I want to do, is there a more efficient way using C# with a winform (maybe a mapping within a dictionary or any object) ?
Also, I found out that in the datagridview, either I can click on a cell and gets its value that can be a good starting point or I can directly change my entire column 1 in hyperlink cells.

What would be the best options ??
Thanks in advance for helping

**UPDATE**

After clicking one of the cells in the first column I make a new form pops up.
In my idea, this form will contain one listbox for languages, another for the document's type to get those inputs and build the string output with:

```
private void dataGridViewDoc_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var ID = dataGridViewDoc.CurrentCell.Value;
        if (dataGridViewDoc.CurrentCell == null ||
            dataGridViewDoc.CurrentCell.Value == null ||
            e.RowIndex == -1) return;
        if (dataGridViewDoc.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(0))
        {
            var FormDocument = new FormDocument();
            FormDocument.ISINTextBoxValue = (string)ID;
            FormDocument.TopMost = true;
            FormDocument.Show();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Usually I fill a DGV with a DataTable (use an adapter from a databae query for the table).  Then from the DataTable is Use dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("id"))

Comment: @jdweng thanks, that's what I do for filling the DGV too.
So you iterate through your dgv's cells if I understand it well. I post an update of my code, now I need to find out the most efficient way to built my string

Comment: Why do you need a string?  You can pass the form any c# object.

Comment: because, I need to reach the documents at their adress. The adress of the electricity bill in English of the person3 wont be the same as the adress of the electricity bill in Italian... one will be something like C//folder//Person3//electricitybill_EN and the other one: C//folder//Person3//electricitybill_IT

Comment: You can do the same as you did in excel.  A worksheet is a two dimension object with rows and columns.  So you can create a two dimensional object in c#.  I usually use a DataTable but you can also use List<List<string>> or a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you guy's for your ideas.

For those who'll face the same thing, what I did it's just made a constant variable with a datatable built exactly the same way a spreadhsheet would be !